# Getting error in requesting a tunnel to local server using localtunnel?

Tags: localtunnel

Error: connection refused: localtunnel.me:37244 (check your firewall settings)

```
your url is: https://pretty-skun-91.localtunnel.me
/usr/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/bin/client:65
        throw err;
        ^

Error: connection refused: localtunnel.me:37244 (check your firewall settings)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/lib/TunnelCluster.js:47:32)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```